# Rails simple form button text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have tried these formats and others.   What format is needed to change the text on the simple form button?   Thanks!

```
<%= f.button :submit, :label => 'Assign', class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>

<%= f.button :submit, 'Assign', class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>

<%= f.button :submit, input_html: { :label => 'Assign' etc } %>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to display label for submit button. Following would give you what you want

`<%= f.submit 'Assign', class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>`

Comment: Got it!   Now I can go make lunch.